# multi_index container in shared memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, shared-memory, multi-index

I have this struct:

```
struct myData
{   
    unsigned long id;
    int age; 
    int phone;

    myData(){};
    myData(unsigned long id_, int age_, int phone_)
        :id(id_),age(age_),phone(phone_){}
    ~myData(){};
};
```

This multi_index container:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    myData, 
        indexed_by<    
            random_access<>,  // keep insertion order
            ordered_non_unique< member<myData, int, &myData::age> >
        >
> myDataContainerType;

typedef myDataContainerType::nth_index<1>::type myDataContainerType_by_Id;
myDataContainerType myDataContainer;
```

and this insert function:

```
bool insert(unsigned long id, int age, int phone) { 

    myDataContainerType::iterator it; 
    bool success; 
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(mutex); // LOCK
    std::pair<myDataContainerType::iterator, bool> result = myDataContainer.push_back(myData(id, age, phone)); 
    it = result.first; 
    success = result.second; 
    if (success) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false; 
}
```

so I would like to put this muti_index container to `shared memory` to make it accesible from other applications as well. I saw [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.additional_containers.multi_index) and [that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/example/ip_allocator.cpp) example, but I didn't understand that `allocator` stuff at all (why do I need a char allocator? What kind of allocator do ı need to use here etc...)

Can somebody explain me how to put this container to shared memory?

Thanks indeed...

**EDIT:**

Ok I added my code this:

```
myDataContainerType *myDataContainer ;

void createInSharedMemory()
{
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only,"mySharedMemory", 65536);

    myDataContainer = segment.construct<myDataContainerType>
        ("MyContainer")            //Container's name in shared memory
        ( myDataContainerType::ctor_args_list()
        , segment.get_allocator<myData>());  //Ctor parameters

}
```

and try to insert the data like that:

```
bool insert(unsigned long id, int age, int phone) { 

    myDataContainerType::iterator it; 
    bool success; 
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(mutex); // LOCK
    std::pair<myDataContainerType::iterator, bool> result = myDataContainer->insert(MyData(id, age, phone));    

    it = result.first; 
    success = result.second; 
    if (success) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false; 
}
```

but I'm getting this error in insert line: (in offset_ptr.hpp)

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000000013fa84748 in LDB_v1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000001d200d0.
```

any idea please???

Comment: you need a char allocator to allocate contiguous regions of `char` objects. You know, which is what you do when you allocate strings? (It's pretty clear from the sample). Please show us the actual code and where you are stuck. At this moment it looks like you're expecting us to do your work?

Comment: The problem is I didn't understand if I have an allocator like the one in example but since I don't have string I guess I don't need that allocator as well. So I think I have to buil it like this example. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.additional_containers.multi_index. How can I reach the container from the other applications? Sorry I'm not expecting you to do the work but simply I don't know how to do it? This is the first time I'm working with shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether `myDataContainer`is non-null after the call to `segment.construct`? Maybe you need to use `segment.find_or_construct` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just figured out that if i take the line starting with managed_shared_memory... outside the function it works without error. I think it must be global. By the way how will other applications reach my container?

Comment: To reach the same container use the same names "mySharedMemory" and "MyContainer" for the memory manager and the container, repectively.

Comment: I get the idea but I have problem with the syntax. I have to reach the container from reader applications and perform search and retreive data from it. Do you have any example code works like that? Thank you very much.

Comment: The same `find_or_construct` code for constructing the container in the writer process can be used to access the container from a reader process. The rest is usual synchronized usage of a `multi_index_container*`.